# Custom exception handler for invalid UUIDs

Tags: c#, uuid

This is my method to retrieve the motherboard's UUID relying on the `Win32_ComputerSystemProduct` struct.

```
    #region "UUID"
    public static string getUUID()
    {
        string UUID = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_ComputerSystemProduct");
            ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();

            foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
            {
                UUID = mo.Properties["UUID"].Value.ToString();
                break;
            }

            UUID = "";

            if (UUID.Equals(string.Empty)
                || UUID.Equals("")
                || UUID.Equals(null)
                || UUID.Equals("FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF")
                || UUID.Equals("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"))
            {
                throw new System.Exception("UUID is invalid.");
            }
            return UUID;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error Message: " + ex.Message);
        }
        return UUID;
    }
    #endregion
```

I have a built-in exception handler which throws an error in-case the strings are the ones I listed, since C# implicitly doesn't know that a string like `FFF...FFF` is invalid/error.

I redefined `UUID = "";` to test this method, say, in case the user running this script has a blank UUID.

I was wondering -- is this the right way to do it? I am unsure about the `return UUID` which still returns the UUID even if it's blank, or `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: `.Equals(string.Empty)` and `.Equals("")` are identical.

Comment: `.IsNullOrEmpty` should be used here.

Comment: Are you sure? I read that they're minutely different. Oh well, it doesn't make a performance difference, so I'll just leave it in there.

Comment: There are quite a few things wrong with this code, better to post on - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "quite a few things wrong with this code"?

Comment: Why catch your own excpeption?  Since you're just going to log the error anyway, just log the error and don't bother throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, prior to your if statement, you set the UUID to null.

Next, your if should look like this:

```
        if (String.IsNullorEmpty(UUID)
            || UUID.Equals("FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF")
            || UUID.Equals("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"))
        {
            throw new System.Exception("UUID is invalid.");
        }
        return UUID;
```

Other then that, this whole if statement should be in the `foreach`.

Comment: I cannot do `UUID.IsNullorEmpty`, but I can do `string.IsNullOrEmpty(UUID)`. Is that the same?

Comment: yes, that's the same thing.  Sorry, just more or less trying to get function across.  Will edit post.

Comment: Thanks, I've made changes.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage - You may wish to use IsNullOrWhitespace if you're using .Net 4

Comment: Would that detect `Empty` like `string.Empty` or `""`?

Comment: yes, Chris is right.  .Net 4 used `Whitespace` instead of `empty`.